# If statement is hit multiple times while matching csv line with word in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, csv

I am currently trying to write an script which is checking if a word in a file matches with a line of a csv file. But when running my script the if statement which checks for matches is being hit multiple times.

Content of my csv file:

```
replace
one
.
.
.
nine
.
.
.
ninety
.
.
.
ninety-nine
```

Content of my sample_file:

```
the apple costs ninety-nine cents
```

This is my code:

```
import csv

with open(csvfile_sample) as csvfile, open(sample_file,'r') as sample,open(new_file,'w') as new:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    lines2 = sample.readlines()
    for line in reader:
        for lines in lines2:                   
            if line['replace'] in lines:                        
                new.write(line['replace'])
```

What the new file is looking after running the script:

```
nine ninety ninety-nine
```

What the new file should look after running the script:

```
ninety-nine
```

So my question is basically what I am doing wrong and how I can avoid those multiple if hits.

Thank's for every suggestion and help in advance:)

EDIT: Writing the csv file in reverse and then accessing it is not solving the problem. The right word is at the right place after running the script but because the loop is not breaking after the first iteration the other words are written down behind it. I've already tried to set up an `break` statement after `new.write(line['replace'])`. But the loop is not breaking when running my script. Is there someone who can tell me why the loop is not breaking and how I can fix this problem?

Comment: The ordering matters.  Basically, you need the lines in reverse order so you hit "ninety-nine" before "ninety" or "nine", and you need to stop looking as soon as you find a hit.  If you can have more than one hit in a line, then you may need to split the line on spaces, or else add spaces before and after your search words so it finds whole words.

Comment: @TimRoberts I just wrote my file in reverse order. When I tested it the same thing just happend in reverse. I need to somehow break the loop after iterating through it one time. Any ideas?

Comment: How about creating two list one from csv file and one from the sample file and checking if an element of sample file list is in csv list. For example you could use `sample.read().split(' ')` to create a list of words (assuming space is a valid delimiter).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve your problem, as described in the comments.  The first way is to break the loop when you get a hit, but since you (for some reason) made the words list the outer loop, you have to set a flag:

```
import csv

with open(csvfile_sample) as csvfile, open(sample_file,'r') as sample,open(new_file,'w') as new:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    lines2 = sample.readlines()
    for line in reader:
        found = False
        for lines in lines2:                   
            if line['replace'] in lines:                        
                new.write(line['replace'])
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            break
```

A better solution would make the OUTER loop run through the lines of text, and the inner loop run through the keywords:

```
import csv

with open(csvfile_sample) as csvfile, open(sample_file,'r') as sample,open(new_file,'w') as new:
    reader = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
    for text in sample.readlines():                   
        for word in reader:
            if word['replace'] in text:                        
                new.write(word['replace'])
                break
```

However, even with this there are issues.  If a line says "I have three cats and four dogs", what do you want?  Do you want both numbers to be printed?  Neither of the solutions above will allow you to both (a) print 'three' and 'four' and (b) NOT print both 'nine' and 'ninety' for 'ninety-nine'.  If that's what you want, then you need to worry about word boundaries.

```
import csv

with open(csvfile_sample) as csvfile, open(sample_file,'r') as sample,open(new_file,'w') as new:
    reader = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
    for text in sample.readlines():
        for word in reader:
            if ' '+line['replace']+' ' in lines:                        
                new.write(line['replace'])
```

Or split each input line into individual words::

```
import csv

with open(csvfile_sample) as csvfile, open(sample_file,'r') as sample,open(new_file,'w') as new:
    words = [x['replace'] for x in csv.DictReader(csvfile)]
    for text in sample.readlines():
        for word in text.strip().split():
            if word in words:                        
                new.write(word)
```